# Docker-Toolbox & Win7 | permission denied on Volume-Select

Tags: mysql, docker, volume, docker-toolbox, kitematic

I use Win7 with DockerToolbox 18.03. and I have somhow trouble with getting volumes running, so I started trying it with Kitematic:

I run a container from *mysql* and in the option "volumes" I see the entry
Dockerfolder: `/var/lib/mysql`  .. and the Localfolder: `No Fodler` .. when I try to change it to whatever, I get a Error: `Invalid directory - Please make sure the directory exists and you can read/write to it`.

But how would I allow that? btw. the directory definetly exists, so it has to be somewhat permission-thing?

The default-path is there `~\Documents\Kitematic\mysql\var\lib` .. but I can't change that(?)

I have googled and found some older [issues](https://github.com/docker/toolbox/issues/607), but they assume do downgrade dockerToolbox to v1.xx .. that was 2017.. now there is v19.x .. I don't think downgrade would be helpful here, would it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the answer. On win7 and DockerToolbos it is not possible to have volumes declared outside your local User-Directory.

https://github.com/docker/kitematic/issues/2738